# How to access control on MainForm from other Thread without coupling?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have few controls on my MainForm in Winforms application. For example control that updates progress of each operation. These operations are classes which in run in different Thread.

How can i properly update those controls ?

Comment: here is the link that solves your situation:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-gui-from-another-thread-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your main form you can add a function like this one

```
private delegate void doSomethingWithTheControlsDelegate(object obj);

public void doSomethingWithTheControls(object obj) {
 if (this.InvokeRequired) {
   this.BeginInvoke(new doSomethingWithTheControlsDelegate(this.doSomethingWithTheControls), obj);
 } else {
   // do something
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, What does else means in this context?

Comment: if you have a pointer to your control in your thread operation you can call control.doSomethingWithTheControls(progress);

Answer (score 1):

the best way is to do that by events.
the easier way is to change them directly.

ensure that they are public and you overgive them to the class and then you can change it

```
Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { frmMain.label1.Text = "bla"; }));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a model class which would contain the data which is displayed to the user. Databind your UI controls to the properties of the model, and update the model values from the worker threads (using appropriate invokations to ensure the update occurs on the UI thread so that you don't get the cross thread exception)

Comment: Well, i do want to implement it but don't know how. If you have some working example in bookmarks/favorites i would love to read it. Thanks